# How can I change the character a string pointer points to?

Tags: c++, string, pointers

It's simple enough in theory:

If I have a string animal = `"Boar"`;

How can I point animal to the `'O'`?

I've tried this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    string *spoint = new string;
    string word = "Hello";
    spoint = &word;
    spoint++;
    cout << (*spoint);

    return 0;
}
```

And it doesn't work.

I want `cout << word;` first to print `"Word"`, if that's the string word points to, then run an operation, so `cout << word;` will print `"ord"`.

There must be a simple way?

Comment: What did you think spoint++ did?

Comment: Maybe you want to use the [c_str](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) mechanism?

Comment: On a sidenote: you have a memory leak there. You allocate a string and then proceed to lose the pointer, thus making it impossible to `free` its memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing some basic **pointer arithmetic**. Lets take the following code snippet:

```
 int* spoint;
 spoint++;
```

If `spoint` points to a `int` whose address is `1000`,then after the above operation, `spoint` will point to the location `sizeof(int)`  bytes next to the current location, because the next `int` will be available at `1000 + sizeof(int)`.This operation will move the pointer to the next memory location `1004` (if size of `int` is `4` bytes) without impacting the actual value at the memory location.

Same case is with the strings.

```
string word[] = {"Hello","world"};
string* spoint = word;
spoint++;
```

After the `spoint++` the `spoint` will point to `"world"` not to the char `e` of `"Hello"` , that is why you didn't the right output.If you want to access the characters in the string you should use a `char*` as mentioned by others.

First you have to convert `word` into a **C-string**(a null-terminated sequence of characters),while assigning it to `char*` ,then you can increment it to access the characters.

```
string word = "word";
const char *spoint = word.c_str();
spoint++;
cout <<spoint<<endl;
```

Now the `spoint` will point to the `'o'` of `"word"` after incrementing,and if you will print it using `cout` then output will be `"ord"`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Rajeev. I don't have enough rep to upvote you, but that is the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I feel like you are confusing `char *` with C++ `string` objects.

By using both you can achieve something similar to what you are asking --although I am not sure that this is what you really want

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    string word = "Hello";
    const char* spoint = word.c_str()
    spoint++;
    cout << (*spoint);

    return 0;
}
```